# creating an sqlite database from an external file with a class object

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to create a database from an external sqlite file using this python class, but I'm getting this error message:

> query() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

I think I understand the issue, but I don't know a way around it, can someone point me in the right direction?

```
class DatabaseManager:
    def __init__(self, db):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
        self.conn.commit()
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()

    def query(self, arg):
        self.test_setup = open(arg)
        self.executescript(test_setup.read())  
        self.cur.execute(arg)
        self.con.commit()
        return self.cur

    def __del__(self):
        self.conn.close()

dbmgr = DatabaseManager("testdb.db")
dbmgr.query('test_setup.sql', 'r')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `query` only takes one argument `arg` but you pass in `self` (implicitly) and `'test_setup.sql'` and `'r'`. Given that you don't use the `'r'` you should probably only call:

```
dbmgr = DatabaseManager("testdb.db")
dbmgr.query('test_setup.sql')
```

Comment: I don't use the 'r'? I'm getting more errors if I exclude it.            `AttributeError: 'DatabaseHandler' object has no attribute 'executescript'`

Comment: @cashmeer `'r'` is the default `mode` for `open` so you don't need to explicitly give it - and [`execute`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.execute) doesn't take an `'r'` parameter if you don't use any parameters in your sql,

Answer (score 0):

if you take a look at your declaration of queryfor your class you will see that you got two parameters: self and arg

However when you call your query function, there are three parameters that are passed: the implicit self that you don't need to mention, the db and the parameter.

If you want arg to be a multiple argument you will need to rewrite it like this : *arg. Otherwise, you can modify your query declaration for three parameters.

Keep in mind that *arg is iterable and you might need to deconstruct it before passing it to your other functions.

For further reading about *args and **kwargs you can visit this website: [*args and **kwargs in python](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/)